# Do people “go half/halves” on something?

Tags: word-usage, idiom-requests, fractions

If two people want to buy a car together, would they go half on the car or halves. Example: Let's go half on this car or Let's go halves on this car?

Comment: "halves" would be more common. Though each person contributes only one half, "let's" means "let us" so it means the two of them together, accounting for both halves.  If it's young kids dividing something, we used to call that "_halvesies_" (hav-zeez) Related: If two people go on a date in America, and each pays their share of the cost, it's called **going Dutch**.

Comment: There's also "half and half", although it's mainly used to describe _mixtures or combinations of different kinds/flavors_, such as food, e.g.:  "Do you want white meat (chicken), dark meat, or half and half?" This is also a common name for milk/cream mixture:  "Do you take cream or milk with your tea?" "I use Half and Half."

Comment: "50-50" is another common possibility. While "go half" sounds bad, "go halves" or "go half-half"  or "go half-&-half" sound okay.

Comment: "Go halvsies" is an informal term often used in the US.

Answer (score 3):

It is ***Let us go halves***, or *Let me go half, and you go half*.

***Let us go half*** would propose that collectively we contribute 50%, allowing some other party or parties to supply the rest.