# How is "Let's do halves" used?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, idiom-meaning

I played the game [Fantasy Maiden's Odd Hideout](http://fantasy-maidens-odd-hideout.wikia.com/wiki/Fantasy_Maiden%27s_Odd_Hideout_Wiki). The game has "Let's do halves" as [Meaningful Echo](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MeaningfulEcho).

One usage example in the game:

> Both main characters have a do(ugh)nut. They share it, and say "let's do halves".

I have done some research, I found [Do people “go half/halves” on something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238805/do-people-go-half-halves-on-something). The question asks about "go" instead" of "do". According to answer, "Let's go halves" mean 50% contributions each (work, money, investment ...). However, from the usage of "Let's do halves" in the game, I feel like it means share thing equally (you and me, each have half of the donut).

I would like to know:

- How the sentence can be used in real world, in writing, speaking,
  both formal and casual.
- Is it an idiom (I have not found any evidence so far)?
- What is it mean ? ( please explain as detail as possible)
- Is the sentence similar to "Let's go halves" ?. (Can we interchange
  "go" and "do" without changing its meaning?). If "Let's do halves" is different from "Let's go halves", what is the difference.

Comment: It's informal. It means *Let's split it equally*. *Go*, *do* -- same thing.

Comment: I did check " Do people “go half/halves” on something?" but I feel that it is not the same. Therefore, I also ask for comparision. By the ways, "Let's do halves" is actually used in the game.

Comment: It's the same thing.

Comment: There's a technique of sharing that's intended to be fair, where one person cuts the item in half, and the other picks their portion. This avoids the possibility that the cutter will deliberately make one piece larger than the other and then select that piece for themselves. I wonder if this is what "do halves" refers to.